# I want to print the prime factors for a number, for example when I enter 120 it gets 2 2 2 3 5 out

Tags: python, math, prime-factoring

**I found this code on the Internet and it works well, but why when you enter the value of zero, does not work
Why when I enter 0 the loop doesn't stop**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgva8.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code and ask a question?

Comment: where is the code you found?

Comment: Please take your time to write down whatever code you are using - it is a lot easier for everyone than to read it from a picture

Comment: 0 is not a prime, you can stop trying.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the while section of your code - because 0 divided by 2 will give a 0 mod always, then you append the number two to a list (li), then update n to be n/2 which is still 0 - then it loops again and again - as your while condition remains true forever...